# could not copy dll when starting selenium ui test in .NET framework

Tags: .net, selenium

I have been using Selenium in .Net Core for some time. I have now tried to use in in a .Net framework application. I usually start the application first and then runs the test. This works in .Net Core but for some reason i get these error messages in .Net framework:

> Could not copy ".dll". Exceeded retry count of 10.failed

I am not sure how this is supposed to work or how its done before .Net Core